# Send data to server when iOS App crashed

Tags: swift, crash, backend

I have used below method to send some data to the server When user properly closed the app,

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
```

Now I want to know, Is it possible to send some sort of data to server when App crashed ? If so What method can I use.

Comment: unfortunately I don't believe there is a way... when an app crashes it won't be able to do anything before it crashes because, quite frankly, how would it know that it crashed. Also, realistically speaking, you shouldn't have to account for that because your app should be programmed to never crash. In the case that for whatever reason the app crashes that's out of your control, then there's not much you can do anyways. Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Take a look at the excellent open source work done on https://www.plcrashreporter.org/.

In general there's very little you can safely do while an app is crashing. Even recording data about the crash is tricky (you may not be able to safely allocate any additional memory during the crash). Instead you probably want to record the information you want to report but defer actually sending it until the next time the app launches.